# sqlite content does not match tkinter table

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

What the title says, when inserting the sql content in the tkinter table everything is put in a single column and the others are not used, any idea what I'm doing wrong? I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W2kAF9pKPPE&t=1572s), it does exactly what I say at minute 40:50.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import font as tkFont
from tkinter import messagebox
import sqlite3

db = 'Inventario-Avigranja.db'

def run_query(query, parametros = ()):
    with sqlite3.connect(db) as conn:
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        result = cursor.execute(query, parametros)
        conn.commit()
    return result

credenciales = ['Walter', 'allboys']

def cambiar_ventana(frame):
    frame.tkraise

def inventarioAdmin():
    cambiar_ventana(f4)
    f2.destroy()
    root.title('Avigranja - Inventario')
    f4.grid(padx=10, pady=10, ipadx=5, ipady=5)

    # Control de inventario y ventas
    agr = Button(f4, text='Añadir un producto', font='20', bg='red', padx=10)
    agr.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10)
    eli = Button(f4, text='Eliminar un producto', font='20', bg='blue', padx=10)
    eli.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10)
    edit = Button(f4, text='Editar un producto', font=20, bg='yellow', padx=10)
    edit.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=10)
    verVentas = Button(f4, text='Ver las ventas', font=20, bg='cyan')
    verVentas.grid(row=0, column=3, padx=10)

    # Tabla del inventario
    tabla = ttk.Treeview(height=15, columns=('#1', '#2', '#3'))
    tabla.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=4, padx=0, pady=0, ipadx=0, ipady=0, sticky=EW)
    tabla['show'] = 'headings'
    tabla.heading('#1', text='Nombre', anchor=CENTER)
    tabla.heading('#2', text='Precio por kilo', anchor=CENTER)
    tabla.heading('#3', text='Stock (en kg)', anchor=CENTER)

    def get_products():
        # Limpio la tabla
        records = tabla.get_children()
        for elementos in records:
            tabla.delete(elementos)
        # Pido la data
        query = 'SELECT * FROM Productos ORDER BY idProducto ASC'
        db_filas = run_query(query)
        for fila in db_filas:
            tabla.insert('', 0, values=fila[1])
            tabla.insert('', 0, values=fila[2])
            tabla.insert('', 0, values=fila[3])

    get_products()

root = Tk()
f1 = Frame(root)
f2 = Frame(root)
f3 = Frame(root)
f4 = Frame(root)

root.mainloop()
```

I removed the code that doesn't involve anything from that section

Comment: What you've done adds three rows, not one row with four items.  I suspect you want one `tabla.insert('', 0, values=fila)` instead of three inserts.

Comment: Yeah, I originally used just one insert but I didn't know how to add more items in the table, how could I do that?